# "conda info" command yields this error

Tags: windows, python, anaconda

After installing Anaconda onto Windows 10 (64-bit), if I open the Anaconda Prompt, I can execute "conda info" with no problems. I added C:/Users/DJ/Anaconda3 and C:/Users/DJ/Anaconda3/Scripts to the system path. In the Windows Command Prompt, typing "python" gets me to the python interpreter. However, if I type "conda info" I get the following output:

C:\Users\DJ>conda info

## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1043, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from libarchive.exception import ArchiveError as _LibarchiveArchiveError
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .entry import ArchiveEntry
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 27, in <module>
    libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

`$ C:\Users\DJ\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py info`

What's causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

For resolving this above problem, We have 2 Ways :

1 - You can work with "**Anaconda Prompt**" separately

Press "**Windows**" Button and search "**Anaconda Prompt**" and Use it.
 "**conda info**" command will be executed successfully.

2 - You can also use "**Command Prompt**"

First, Select your Installation path of "**Anaconda**" (in which the folder "Anaconda" folder is present).

Complete Path : **C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3**

For Example: **Use this Path => C:\ProgramData**

Now, After setting up your path, you have to use the command "**activate root**".

For Example: Path => **C:\ProgramData> activate root**

Now you will get "**(base)**" as a prefix in the path.

For Example: Path => **(base) C:\ProgramData>**

Now, we can execute "**conda info**" command.

For Example: Path => **(base) C:\ProgramData>conda info**